# Translation of 'Select' which contains grouping parameter without composition is not supported

Tags: ef-core-6.0

While working on migration from .net5 to .net6 I came across a problem with Entity Framework (running against SqlServer database)

```
AppDbContext context = _provider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
var grp = from d in context.Devices
    group d by d.CreatedOn.Day
    into grp2
    select grp2;
Assert.IsTrue(grp.Count() > 0); //this throws an exception
```

The error description is not very intuitive I think:

> Translation of 'Select' which contains grouping parameter without
> composition is not supported.

To fix this I simply had to add an orderby, but can't understand why this is required.

```
AppDbContext context = _provider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
var grp = from d in context.Devices
    group d by d.CreatedOn.Day
    into grp2
    orderby grp2.Key
    select grp2;
Assert.IsTrue(grp.Count() > 0); //this throws exception
```

Has anyone come across this issue before? Am I missing something? Interestingly enough, this is not a problem with EF Core 5, the query works as is without the orderby.

Comment: Having the same problem